# Python Twitter Statistics

Tags: python, twitter

I need to get the number of people who have followed a certain account by month, also the number of people who have unfollowed the same account by month, the total number of tweets by month, and the total number of times something the account tweeted has been retweeted by month.

I am using python to do this, and have installed python-twitter, but as the documentation is rather sparse, I'm having to do a lot of guesswork. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction? I was able to get authenticated using OAuth, so thats not an issue, I just need some help with getting those numbers.

Thank you all.

Comment: to be honest, not much, I've just been digging around in python-twitter, and have found where to get the total number of followers curently for a user, but nowhere that allows me to specify a date range, and nowhere that can get the number of people who followed/unfollowed a user

Comment: even a list of people who have followed/unfollowed a user and the dates when they did so would work, as I could process them and figure out the numbers I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem is I also need to get unfollow statistics, which twittercounter does not supply.

My solution was to access the twitter REST API directly, using the oauth2 library in python. I found this very simple compared to some of the other twitter libraries for python out there. This example was particularly helpful: http://parand.com/say/index.php/2010/06/13/using-python-oauth2-to-access-oauth-protected-resources/

Comment: forgot to add, I'm using the current follower IDs function of the twitter API, and calculating the numbers myself, based on previously pulled IDs that are stored in my database.

Comment: While the Twittercounter API doesn't directly have an unfollow stat, I calculate the net change in followers by looking at the `followersperdate` array in the results.

Answer (score 1):

These types of statistical breakdowns are not generally available via the Twitter API.  Depending on your sample date range, you may have luck using [Twittercounter.com](http://twittercounter.com/)'s [API](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api) (you can sign up for an API key [here](http://twittercounter.com/pages/api-signup/)).

The API is rate limited to 100 calls per hour, unless you get whitelisted. You can get results for the previous 14 days. An example request is below:

```
http://api.twittercounter.com?twitter_id=813286&apikey=[api_key]
```

The results, in JSON, look like this:

```
{"version":"1.1","username":"BarackObama","url":"http:\/\/www.barackobama.com","avatar":"http:\/\/a1.twimg.com\/profile_images\/784227851\/BarackObama_twitter_photo_normal.jpg","followers_current":7420937,"date_updated":"2011-04-16","follow_days":"563","started_followers":"2264457","growth_since":5156480,"average_growth":"9166","tomorrow":"7430103","next_month":"7695917","followers_yesterday":7414507,"rank":"3","followers_2w_ago":7243541,"growth_since_2w":177396,"average_growth_2w":"12671","tomorrow_2w":"7433608","next_month_2w":"7801067","followersperdate":{"date2011-04-16":7420937,"date2011-04-15":7414507,"date2011-04-14":7400522,"date2011-04-13":7385729,"date2011-04-12":7370229,"date2011-04-11":7366548,"date2011-04-10":7349078,"date2011-04-09":7341737,"date2011-04-08":7325918,"date2011-04-07":7309609,"date2011-04-06":7306325,"date2011-04-05":7283591,"date2011-04-04":7269377,"date2011-04-03":7257596},"last_update":1302981230}
```

The retweet stats aren't available from Twittercounter, but you might be able to obtain those from [Favstar](http://favstar.fm/) (although they don't have a public API currently.)